# Identify div with no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two parent div with it's corresponding child div's. I want to modify something in my second div's child div but it has no id.How will I do that without affecting the first parent div's child div?

```
<div class="main">        
    <div id="loggedin" class="container-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: When you query something by class, you'll get an indexed collection.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(".main:eq(1) .container-fluid");
```

or

```
$(".main:eq(1)").find(".container-fluid");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f4cfh6kx/14/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.eq()` selector here:

```
$('.main .container-fluid:eq(1)');
```

or `:not` selector:

```
$('.main .container-fluid:not(#loggedin)');
```

Comment: Your first selection would return two divs.

Comment: Yeah I see, my bad. I thought it would select all 2nd divs inside all .main, instead it selects all divs inside all .main then you take the 2nd one. How would you select all 2nd divs inside all `.main`s?

Answer (score 0):

And a pure javascript solution:

```
var elems=document.getElementsByClassName("container-fluid");
var item=elems[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need of

```
$('.main').eq(1).children('div').text()
```

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/v8ppc3xq/) fiddle

For more DOM traversals go through [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) link